# finding the highest and lowest number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

const int SIZE = 10;
int values[SIZE];   
int count;          
int largest;        
int smallest;       

cout << "Enter 10 integer values and I'll tell you the largest and the smallest number." << endl;

for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    cout << "\nEnter an integer value: ";
    cin  >> values[count];
}

largest = smallest = values[0];
for (count = 1; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    if (values[count] > largest)
        largest = values[count];
    if (values[count] < smallest)
        smallest = values[count];
}


cout << "\nThe largest value entered is " << largest << endl;
cout << "The smallest value entered is " << smallest << endl << endl;


 system("pause");
  return 0;   

}
```

Hello guys this is my program here, it's a program to find out the highest and the lowest number I want to ask a few questions.

For the first for loop, they assigned the count to 0 initially, but for the 2nd loop it was assigned to 1.

Also the part where:
largest = smallest = values[0];

why so? and what is values[0]?

please help

Comment: *Read* what it says. Read what the program is doing in the first loop. Read what it is doing in the 2nd loop. Read what it is comparing to. What is value of `largest` when it enters 2nd loop? Do you see now why it skips the first number?

Comment: Imagine if there was only one number instead of ten. The first (and only) number would be both the smallest and the largest, and what would you compare it against?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    cout << "\nEnter an integer value: ";
    cin  >> values[count];
}
```

loops `SIZE` (10) amount of times and gets user's input. Puts the input of each time into an array (`values`).

```
largest = smallest = values[0];
```

means that `smallest` and `largest` start using the first item in the array.

```
for (count = 1; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    if (values[count] > largest)
        largest = values[count];
    if (values[count] < smallest)
        smallest = values[count];
}
```

is where we loop through the array `values` (that we got from user) and check to see if `largest` is not larger than the current item. If it's not, we set `largest` to the larger value.

We do the same for `smallest` and check to see if `smallest` is not smaller than the current item. If it's not, we set `smallest` to the smaller value.

Comment: so I understand that values[0] is the first number in the array, which is the first number the user enters? and since we already have a number, we will run the loop one less time than before, hence the count =1?

Comment: yes. In the second loop, the program is trying to figure out the largest and smallest values. Before it starts that loop, it sets both `smallest` and `largest` to that first item. Then in the loop it can compare each of them to all of the other items in the array(values the user entered later) to see if it can find a smaller or larger value than that first value inputted.

Comment: thanks man, now I get it. I had trouble understanding what value[0] is because from my previous understanding, value[0] would be an array with 0 elements.

Comment: `value[0]` is the first item in the array. `value[1]` would be the second item etc.
When the array was declared `int values[SIZE];` it was set to a size of `SIZE` (10).

Answer (score 1):

values[size] is equals to value[10].
  it simply means value is an array that can hold 10 elements.

```
for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
{
    cout << "\nEnter an integer value: ";
    cin  >> values[count];
}
```

This loop insert 10 elements inside the value array. 
Count is initialized to 0 because array index starts from zero and the first element need to be stored at the very first index.

```
smallest=largest=value[0]
```

it means whatever stored at first index is either the smallest or the largest element.By doing so you can compare rest of the element with the first element to find the smallest or the largest that's why second for loop starts with count=1.

```
    if (values[count] > largest)
        largest = values[count];
    if (values[count] < smallest)
        smallest = values[count];
```

the above code literally means

```
if(values[1]>value[0])
```

because value [0] is already stored in smallest and largest.

Hope This explanation will serve your purpose

Comment: thank you so much for your time, I'd just like it clarified for the last time. So when the first element is stored as the largest and the small number, when we let's say, compare it to the the 2nd number and the 2nd number is greater, so the 2nd number is now stored as the greatest number and so on and forth.